# Can the class called by Spring Integration's Interceptors know the channel that connected the interceptor?

Tags: spring-integration

```
<channel id="simResMsgSndChannel">
    <interceptors>
        <wire-tap channel="simResLogger" />
    </interceptors>
</channel>

<service-activator input-channel="simResLogger"
    ref="simResLoggingService" />
<beans:bean id="simResLoggingService" class="com.sds.afi.log.SimResLoggingService" />
```

In the class "com.sds.afi.log.SimResLoggingService", I want to know "simResMsgSndChannel". How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

you can track message history using message-history element in the configuration.
check [this](http://static.springsource.org/spring-integration/docs/2.0.0.RC1/reference/html/message-history.html) link